# Not all friends displayed using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps

I am using FB.api('me/friends'...) to get the list of facebook friends but, instead of receiving 150 (that are all my FB friends), I only receive 147. Is there any privacy settings that allow users not to appear on this API function results?

Thanks

Comment: Is your app age restricted? It may be filtering out those who are below the required age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any privacy settings that allow users not to appear on this API function results?

Users can totally opt-out from using any kind of apps on Facebook – they call it “turning Platform off”.

This setting can be found under Privacy Settings -> Ads, Apps and Websites:

> *“Turn off your ability to use apps, plugins, and websites on and off Facebook. After you turn this off, we will not store information about you when you use apps or websites off Facebook.”*

After opting out of “the Platform” this way, a friend will not show up on your `/me/friends` connection any more.